# How to modify sequence of strings?

Tags: python, string

Let's consider very simple probem, if I have list:

```
x = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

and I want to transform it by adding "_x" at the end of string. In other words I desirable output is:

```
x = ["a_x", "b_x", "c_x", "d_x", "e_x"]
```

Of course I can just loop over strings:

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    x[i] = x[i] + "_x"
```

But I'm searching of more efficient solution. Could you please give me a hand with doing so?

Comment: Your solution is good. You can make it using list comprehension but it will be neither better nor worse, just different method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify the `list` *in-place*, the only "better" solution is a listcomp that is assigned back to the complete slice of the original `list`:

```
x[:] = [item + '_x' for item in x]
```

which, unlike:

```
x = [item + '_x' for item in x]
```

will modify any aliases that refer to the same original `list` (e.g. if a caller passes such a `list` to a function, the former will modify the caller's `list` as well, the latter will not).

Comment: `x[:] = (item + '_x' for item in x)` will be even better as it doesn't initialize one more list.

Comment: @OlvinRoght: Dirty knowledge here, but sorry, it does initialize another list. Slice assignment *has* to realize the input before performing the assignment, in case the input depends on the values being replaced. Under the hood, CPython calls `PySequence_Fast` on all arguments; if it's already a `list` or `tuple`, this does nothing, but for a genexpr, it realizes it in memory as a `list`. End result: It's slower and more wasteful to use the genexpr, because genexprs have higher overhead to produce the same `list` than the equivalent listcomp would.

Comment: I'll note: In this *specific* case (where each element is being replaced at the same index), theoretically it would be safe if Python assigned without pre-listifying. But it's basically impossible for it to know it's safe, so rather than be wrong in many cases, CPython (and likely most interpreters of Python) listifies in all cases to ensure correctness.

Comment: I haven't sniff sources, but I remember few years ago I've done test with large list where I monitored memory consumption and peak memory usage in code with generator expression was significantly lower.

Comment: I've made some tests with different list size and you're right, peak usage is the same with generator and list comprehension. I haven't noticed any difference in performance though, expressions are almost equal.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Getting items from list is surprisingly faster. I said surprisingly because (here is my test  `timeit("''.join(['a' for i in range(100000)])", number=1000)` ) I thought a list has to be created once (first iteration) and another iteration has to be done to get items from the list(second iteration) so That would be slow. But I saw that overhead of yielding items from generators are noticeable. Try to run it with generator expression this time. btw thanks @ShadowRanger for this detailed comment.

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary, your case is different from assigning generator to slice.

Comment: @OlvinRoght: Although it's a similar case where internal details matter. `''.join` is another case where CPython pre-listifies generators. Unlike the assign to slice case, it doesn't have to (it could build the string incrementally with a `bytearray`-like internal thing with an amortized expansion trick, instead of prewalking to calculate final length then allocating once in bulk), but CPython does, so `''.join(gen expr here)` loses (slightly) to `''.join([same expr as listcomp])`. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @ShadowRanger, that's well-known case, few times in my answers I've attached link to original question where the difference have been explained. I just didn't know that slice assignment follow same logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehensions :

```py
print([item + '_x' for item in x])
print([f"{item}_x" for item in x])
```

It's a little bit faster than loops, but definitely more readable.

list comprehensions create new lists, they don't modify the existing list. You can then rebind the result to `x` or do a slice assignment like `x[:] = ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `map()`:

```
[In] list(map(lambda x: x + '_x', your_list))

[Out] ['a_x', 'b_x', 'c_x', 'd_x', 'e_x']
```

Comment: While it's 100% legal, I'd suggest the argument name for the `lambda` not be the same as the name of the `list`; it's allowed (the scopes differ), but it's ripe for confusion.

Comment: Yep, I was just thinking that after I posted this. I will change it.

Answer (score 0):

For in-place modification of the list you can combine map with subscript assignment:

```
x = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

x[:] = map("{}_x".format,x)

print(x)
['a_x', 'b_x', 'c_x', 'd_x', 'e_x']
```